# Grab and move application windows from a .NET app?

Tags: .net, window-handles

Is it possible for a .NET application to grab all the window handles currently open, and move/resize these windows?

I'd pretty sure its possible using P/Invoke, but I was wondering if there were some managed code wrappers for this functionality.

Comment: Use a mechanical turk - just pop up a message box and ask the user to do it for you. Be sure to provide detailed instructions. :P Sorry, just amusing myself here...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using the Windows API.

This post has information on how to get all window handles from active processes: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=35545

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
       IntPtr hWnd;
       foreach(Process proc in procs)
       {
          if ((hWnd = proc.MainWindowHandle) != IntPtr.Zero)
          {
             Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", proc.ProcessName, hWnd);
          }
       }         
    }
 }
```

And then you can move the window using the Windows API: http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/689.html

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

...

MoveWindow((IntPtr)handle, (trackBar1.Value*80), 20 , (trackBar1.Value*80)-800, 120, true);
```

Here are the parameters for the MoveWindow function:

> In order to move the window, we use
>   the MoveWindow function, which takes
>   the window handle, the co-ordinates
>   for the top corner, as well as the
>   desired width and height of the
>   window, based on the screen
>   co-ordinates. The MoveWindow function
>   is defined as:
>
> MoveWindow(HWND hWnd, int nX, int
>   nY, int nWidth, int nHeight, BOOL
>   bRepaint);
>
> The bRepaint flag
>   determines whether the client area
>   should be invalidated, causing a
>   WM_PAINT message to be sent, allowing
>   the client area to be repainted. As an
>   aside, the screen co-ordinates can be
>   obtained using a call similar to
>   GetClientRect(GetDesktopWindow(),
>   &rcDesktop) with rcDesktop being a
>   variable of type RECT, passed by
>   reference.

(http://windows-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/client_area_size_with_movewindow)