# Controlling where (x,y) of a newly opened window in Delphi 2006

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm trying to control the coordinates of where my program opens a new window because currently they're opening ontop of each other.  Does anyone have a working example of how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can always set the .Top and .Left properties manually, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm : TForm;
begin
  frm := TForm.Create(Self);
  frm.Left := 100;  //replace with some integer variable
  frm.Top := 100;  //replace with some integer variable
  frm.Show;
end;
```

However, Windows has a default window placement algorithm that tries to keep the title bars of each window visible.  On my computer, repeated clicks to this Button1 procedure give nicely stacked windows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm : TForm;
begin
  frm := TForm.Create(Self);
  frm.Show;
end;
```

Also, don't forget that you can use the built-in set of TPosition locations:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm : TForm;
begin
  frm := TForm.Create(Self);
  frm.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
  {
  Other possible values:
    TPosition = (poDesigned, poDefault, poDefaultPosOnly, poDefaultSizeOnly,
      poScreenCenter, poDesktopCenter, poMainFormCenter, poOwnerFormCenter);

  //}
  frm.Show;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help!
Do you know of a way to set the x,y of an outside program though? For instance if I open the default browser with my current application the commands you listed wouldn't work :-/

Comment: @kogus: nicely constructed answer (+1)!  It's a shame the OP was not clear.

Answer (score 4):

This type of functionality has been explained for C# in [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140993/grab-and-move-application-windows-from-a-net-app).

Also, for Delphi, check out [Understanding and Using Windows Callback Functions](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/callback_delphi.htm) in Delphi which describes getting handles for windows that are currently open.  And see [Shake a window (form) from Delphi code](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/qt/windowshake.htm) which describes how to move a window once you've got its handle.